# Authenticating requests in Django test client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-testing

My API works when I test it using `Postman` (with the server running). For example:
[image]

When I test using Django test client, I am able to log in, but not to authenticate a request. For example:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + token}
response = client.get('/api/v1/users/auth/user/', **headers)
```

The response object contains:

`'_container': [b'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}']`

For some reason, the token ends up in the `request`, not in headers:

`'request': {'Authorization': 'Token 665c371b1b894abba102cdbae8b35b613321791d',`

What am I missing?

Comment: The second parameter in `get` method is to pass the payload. To add token to header use parameter `extra={ "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"Token {access_token}" }`

Comment: @JaskaranSingh Still getting the same error with `response = client.get('/api/v1/users/auth/user/', extra={ "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"Token {token}" })`

Answer (score 1):

At last I found what works:

```
response = client.get('/api/v1/users/auth/user/', 
                      **{ "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"Token {token}" })
```